# Convertir JSON a CSV en C#

Tags: c#, json, csv

Trato de convertir un Json en csv, pero al pasarlo a un array y deserealizarlo, no me reconoce los headers, no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Esta dentro de un metodo POST en una API Rest en c#.

Me da este error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' no contiene una definición para 'Name'
```

No se que puede estar mal, el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
var content = in_Codes.ToString();
                    dynamic array=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array.data, Formatting.None); // Usar el elemento data del JSON
                    var delimiter = ";";
                    var csv = JsonToCsv(jsonContent, delimiter);
private string JsonToCsv(string jsonContent, string delimiter)
    {
        var data = JsonStringToTable(jsonContent);
        var headers = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)((IEnumerable<dynamic>)data).First()).Select((prop) => prop.Name).ToArray();
        var csvList = new List<string>
{
    string.Join(delimiter, headers.Select((prop) => string.Format(@"""{0}""", prop)).ToArray())
};

        var lines = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)data)
            .Select(row => row)
            .Cast<IEnumerable<dynamic>>()
            .Select((instance) => string.Join(delimiter, instance.Select((v) => string.Format(@"""{0}""", v.Value))))
            .ToArray();

        csvList.AddRange(lines);
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, csvList);
    }

    private static dynamic JsonStringToTable(string jsonContent)
    {
        var json = jsonContent.Split(new[] { '=' }).Last();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    }
```

---

Este es el Json

```json
{
  "data": {
    "master_code": 207211,  
    "parent_sku": " ",      
    "is_unique_size": false,
    "line": {       
      "id": "0108",
      "name": "ALPARGATA"
    },
    "description": "M078",
    "brand": {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "16 HRS"
    },
    "vendor": {
      "id": "XXX",
      "name": "XXX"
    },
    "packing_type": "C", 
    "size_type_id": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "TODAS"
    },
    "sizes": [
      "35",
      "36",
      "37",
      "38",
      "39",
      "40"
    ],
    "dim_type": {
      "code": "C",
      "name": "Color"
    },
    "dim_values": [
      {
        "id": "A01|V89",        
        "name": "NEGRO|SAS.",           
        "ratio": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          3,
          2,
          1
        ],
        "gs_attrs": [
          {
            "code": "COD001",
            "name": "COD TEMP",
            "key": "INV2024",
            "value": "INVIERNO 2024"
          },
          {
            "code": "COD002",
            "name": "ORIGEN",
            "value": "IMP"          
          },
          {
            "code": "COD003",
            "name": "GENERO",
            "key": "F",
            "value": "FEMENINO"
          },
          {
            "code": "COD004",
            "name": "COD MATERIAL",
            "value": "V89"              
          },
          {
            "code": "COD005",
            "name": "COD COLOR HOMOLOGADO",
            "value": "A01"              
          },
          {
            "code": "COD006",
            "name": "TAREA (TT)",
            "value": "DI"
          },
          {
            "code": "COD007",
            "name": "ID CONSIGNATARIO",
            "key": "1000",
            "value": "FABRICA"
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Pone un ejemplo del JSON

Comment: Intente convertirlo con un Datatble como en esta respuesta : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348017/11229077

Comment: Richard, tambien lo probe con esa respuesta pero me da un error que no se como resolverlo. 
Error CS1729 'CsvWriter' no contiene un constructor que tome 1 argumentos